# Laravel Dingo API and issues with Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, middleware, dingo-api

I use Dingo with Laravel 5.1 to create simple API.

So at route.php I have:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function($api) {

    $api->get('getvoucher', 'App\Http\Controllers\BitemsController@index');
    $api->get('update/{key}', 'App\Http\Controllers\BitemsController@update');
    $api->post('store', 'App\Http\Controllers\BitemsController@store');

    $api->post('authenticate', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@authenticate');
$api->post('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@logout');
$api->get('token', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@getToken');

});
```

and my BitemsController is:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $bitem = Bitem::where('key',$request->key)->where('id',$request->pin)->first();

        return $bitem;
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $bitem = new Bitem($request->all());
        $bitem->save;
        return $bitem;
    }
```

Now I use POSTMAN application to test the API, and when I send GET to localhost:8888/api/getvoucher everything is fine, but when I make POST request to store some data then I got error:

```
"message": "500 Internal Server Error",
    "status_code": 500,
    "debug": {
        "line": 53,
        "file": "C:\\wamp\\www\\dine\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\TokenMismatchException",
        "trace": [
```

POSTMAN:
[image]

To fix the problem I try to add:

```
protected $except = [
    'api/*',
];
```

inside middleware VerifyCsrfToken.php but wnt work.

Please tell me how to solve my problem...

Comment: Any Ideas how to fix issue? The same error is at api/authenticate POST route ...

Comment: Can you verify that your application is using your extended `VerifyCsrfToken.php` middleware?

Comment: Yes, i'm using it .. at Kernel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Postman to work, you need to either send the correct CSRF header, or remove the need for it on your routes.

I'm assuming based on your screenshot your Dingo API routes are using [`API_PREFIX=api` in your `.env` file](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Configuration).

Check the [Laravel documentation on CSRF tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) for more information about those. The [gist that @BM2ilabs suggested](https://gist.github.com/ethanstenis/3cc78c1d097680ac7ef0) has some basics on how to find out what CSRF token you're using for local testing in your session to put into Postman.

If you don't want to use CSRF protection, you are correct in using the [`$except` property on the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware as per the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) - this has also [come up on Stack Overflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992885/laravel-5-post-whithout-csrf-checking/32902801#32902801). Tricky to troubleshoot that without seeing your `Kernel` and the full middleware file you're using. If the `$except` property really isn't working for you, you can always override the `VerifyCsrfToken::handle()` method [as per this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-avoiding-csrf-middleware-on-api-post-routes/replies/28994) and add whatever route checks you like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( ! $request->is('api/*'))
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

If you are *only* creating an API that is going to be stateless and not need CSRF protection, you could just comment out the usage of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware in your `Kernel` entirely (and possibly some of the other session middleware), although I would recommend using some kind of authentication/validation that your visitor should be allowed to access the API endpoint.

Comment: The issue comes from my FTP client... FilleZilla tell me that upload is succesfull but it wasnt... I checked manually and see that VerifyCsrfToen is not changed!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `csrf_token` to the post , but that might be tricky with postman

in laravel add the header with what you use 
For example Axios :

```
it already has that integrated
```

jQuery Ajax

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

for more [info's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

**Update**

After some searching i found this article that show how to make csrf work with `POSTMAN`as well

[Gists of @ethanstenis](https://gist.github.com/ethanstenis/3cc78c1d097680ac7ef0)